# How to display date element in html ,when clicked on a textbox field and get value of the selected date?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The requirement: Need to display date element or jquery date picker when a user clicks on the input type - textbox. How to do it?

html code :

```
<tr class="odd">
<td class="col-md-3">DOB</td>
<td  class="col-md-8" id="dob" ><input contenteditable="true" type="text" class="form-control input-lg " name="newDOB" type="text" value="<?php echo $newDate; ?>"/></td></tr>
```

jquery so far tried :

```
$(document).ready(function()
{  
   $('#dob').datepicker();

   $('#dob').focus(function(){
     $('#dob').datepicker('show');
   });

   $('#dob').click(function(){
     $('#dob').datepicker('show');
   });
   //$('#ui-datepicker-div').show();
   $('#dob').datepicker('show');
});
```

Comment: why can't you go with the date type?

Comment: actually in text box its displaying the date from database .

Answer (score 0):

Here you have one datapiker working for multiple dates

```js
$(document).ready(function (){
 var array_names = ["John", "Joseph", "Luis"];
 var dbDate;
 var date2;
 var num = array_names.length;
 var array_dates =["1974-05-30", "1978-11-12", "1980-12-11"];
 for(var i = 0; i<num; i++){
  $("#share").append('<form id = "form_'+array_names[i]+'">');
   $("#form_"+array_names[i]).append('<input type="text" placeholder="Name" name="routename" value = "'+array_names[i]+'" id="name_'+array_names[i]+'">');  
   $("#form_"+array_names[i]).append('<input type="date" placeholder="Date of birth" name="date_birth" value = "'+array_dates[i]+'" id="datepiker_'+array_names[i]+'" class = "datepiker">');
   dbDate =  array_dates[i];
   date2 = new Date(dbDate);
   $("#datepiker_"+array_names[i]).datepicker({
      dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'
   }).datepicker('setDate', date2)
 }
 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<meta charset="utf-8">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <div id = "share">
    </div>
```

Here you have one working for a fixed number of dates

```js
$(document).ready(function (){
 var dbDate;
 var date2;
 var array_dates =["1974-05-30", "1978-11-12", "1980-12-11"];
  var num = array_dates.length;
 for(var i = 0; i<num; i++){
   dbDate =  array_dates[i];
   date2 = new Date(dbDate);
   $("#datepiker_"+i).datepicker({
      dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'
   }).datepicker('setDate', date2)
 }
 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<meta charset="utf-8">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <input type ="datepicker" id = "datepiker_0" value = "" class = "datepicker">
    <input type ="datepicker" id = "datepiker_1" value = "" class = "datepicker">
    <input type ="datepicker" id = "datepiker_2" value = "" class = "datepicker">
```

One with an input text type.

```js
$( function() {
    $( "#datest" ).datepicker({
  changeMonth: true,
  changeYear: true,
  dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy"
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<meta charset="utf-8">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="datest" name="datainiciooferta">
```

To know how it works take a look at this link http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/